# Set session variable from a dropdownlist before postback?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to set session variable from a dropdownlist before postback?

I have 3 DropDownLists. The first `OnSelectedIndexChanges` populates the second, the second populates the third. The third DropDownList has `autopostback` set to `false`, since based on the second dropdownlist selection, the third dropdownlist may only have one value to choose from. Seems kind of useless to make the user select from only one option.

How can I set the session variable from the third dropdownlist without a postback?

Comment: When you post back from the 2nd drop down you check whatever datasource is driving 3rd drop down and set your session variable.

Comment: anything you tried ???

Comment: If your third dropdown has only one item then in second dropdown selected index changed event set that in session. If you have more than one item in dropdown then on html side create onchage event and call session enabled webmethod to add selected item in session. If you are sure that only one item will come in third dropdown then you can set that in second dropdown selected index changed else you have to go to server side to set session.

Comment: @Yogesh - Setting the session variable for the third dropdownlist in the second dropdownlist onselectedindexchanged does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement usually we use ajax to fire server side method to save Session without doing the whole postback. The following codes as a quick sample.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList_family" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_family_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Cat</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Dog</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Bird</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_species" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button_showSession" runat="server" Text="ShowSession" OnClick="Button_showSession_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Use Nuget to install jQuery then

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveSession(input) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SaveSession",
            data: "{'input':'" + input + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#DropDownList_species").on("change", function () {
            SaveSession(this.value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Finally in the codebehind

```
internal static readonly List<string> _cats = new List<string>() { "American Shorthair", "Siamese", "Chinchilla" };
internal static readonly List<string> _dogs = new List<string>() { "Welsh Corgi", "Beagle", "Husky" };
internal static readonly List<string> _birds = new List<string>() { "Parrot" };

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void SaveSession(string input)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["YouWant"] = input;
}

protected void DropDownList_family_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> src = new List<string>();
    if (DropDownList_family.SelectedValue == "Cat")
    {
        src = _cats;
    }
    else if (DropDownList_family.SelectedValue == "Dog")
    {
        src = _dogs;
    }
    else if (DropDownList_family.SelectedValue == "Bird")
    {
        src = _birds;
    }

    if (!src.Any(str => str == "--Please Select--"))
        src.Insert(0, "--Please Select--");

    DropDownList_species.DataSource = src;
    DropDownList_species.DataBind();
}

protected void Button_showSession_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Session["YouWant"]);
}
```

`$("#DropDownList_species").on("change"` will fire function SaveSession which ajax call the server side method `Default.aspx/SaveSession` then it will assgin the input to `Session["YouWant"]`